# Shift an integer array to the left by `n` bits

Tags: arrays, operators, solidity

It seems it should be a straightforward to shift/rotate an array by `n` bits.

However, the programming language I'm using (Solidity) doesn't have any such operator (i.e. there's no shift or rotate operator)...

I have an unsigned, 256-bit integer (which is a Solidity type `uint256`).

I was wondering if I could somehow do a shift or rotate operation "manually"?

I mean, perform some series of multiplication (`*`), mod (`%`) or similar operations to give the desired shift and rotate? I know this could be very inefficient, but I only need to do this operation once or twice an hour so it doesn't matter in my use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't a shift function then you will likely have to do some series of *2 or slightly better would be:

val*[2^(number of shifts)]

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood the way in which solidity works. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, this is a very good observation. One that wasn't immediately obvious to me. I think that just shifts? It puts zeros into the least significant bits? I would like to rotate...

Comment: That would just shift and place 0s in the LSB but as its an unsigned integer that would be fine as long as there wasn't an overflow. For rotating not sure if I can be of much service but here are some examples in different languages. Maybe can be of use to you: 

http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/10/12/rotate-an-array/